# Handling case where null is returned Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to count the number of full stops in a sentence. This code works fine when there is a full stop in the sentence. However, if there isn't a full stop i get an error message saying `Cannot read property 'length' of null`

What is the best way to write my code to handle this error, and display `0` as number of fullstops to the user.

[See js fiddle here for the example](https://jsfiddle.net/3refthee/1/)

**JS**

```
$(".calculate").click(function() {
var input = $(".text-input").val();
var fullStopCount = 0;
   fullStopCount = input.match(new RegExp("\\.", "g")).length;
   $(".fullstop-count").text(". = " + fullStopCount);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="textarea-holder">
  <textarea class="text-input" name="textarea" rows="5" cols="30">This sentence contains one fullstop.</textarea>
</div>
<button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
<p class="fullstop-count"></p>
```

Comment: Use `/\./g` instead of `new RegExp("\\.", "g")`, it's more readable, and may be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation in case no match is found **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** returns `null`, in that case you can't get `length` property of `null`.

Also you can use `/\./g` instead of `new RegExp("\\.", "g")` which will be much faster since it's already a regex object.

```js
$(".calculate").click(function() {
  var input = $(".text-input").val();
  var fullStopCount = 0;
  // if match() returns null ( which is falsy value) returns [] 0therwise the matched array
  fullStopCount = (input.match(/\./g) || []).length;
  $(".fullstop-count").text(". = " + fullStopCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textarea-holder">
  <textarea class="text-input" name="textarea" rows="5" cols="30">This sentence contains one fullstop.</textarea>
</div>
<button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
<p class="fullstop-count"></p>
```

---

**[FYI :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)** More about [short-circuit evaluation of logical operator is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation).

Comment: @phantom : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Just make another `if` (ternary in this example) to check you received results:

```
var fullStops = input.match(new RegExp("\\.", "g"));
var fullStopsCount = fullStops ? fullStops.length : 0;
$(".fullstop-count").text(". = " + fullStopCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if variable is null first to avoid the error

```
if (input.match(new RegExp("\\.", "g")) != null) {
  // check the length...
}
```

Comment: This requires another regexp extraction if you enter the if clause.

Comment: Store the result of that expression in a variable first and then compare

Answer (score 0):

If there are no '.' in the text, `input.match(new RegExp("\\.", "g"))` will return null. You should use `.length` only if there is at least one full stop otherwise you know there are none

```js
$(".calculate").click(function() {
var input = $(".text-input").val();
var fullStopCount = 0;
   fullStopReg = input.match(new RegExp("\\.", "g"));
   if(fullStopReg == null){
       $(".fullstop-count").text(". = 0");
   }
   else{
      fullStopCount = fullStopReg.length;
     $(".fullstop-count").text(". = " + fullStopCount);
   }
   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textarea-holder">
  <textarea class="text-input" name="textarea" rows="5" cols="30">This sentence contains one fullstop.</textarea>
</div>
<button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
<p class="fullstop-count"></p>
```